# FirebaseDatabase display a single value from a single user

Tags: java, android, firebase, mobile, firebase-realtime-database

Working on a small project at the moment on Android Studio and can't work out how I can print a single value from the current user.
I am trying to get the current user's username to print, without printing all of the users other information such as email address...

Here is my database

[image]

I know I've got duplicates of everything, I've fixed that since :P

So far I've managed to print all of the user's details fine (unfortunately every user's details also printed)... using this code:

```
fDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

    fDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String test = (String) dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
            Log.d ("Testing", test);
```

[image]
The output I achieved can be found above.

and this is my User class:

```
class User {
String Displayname;
String Email;
Long createdAt;

public User () {}

public User(String displayname, String email, Long createdAt) {
    this.Displayname = displayname;
    this.Email = email;
    this.createdAt = createdAt;
}

public String getDisplaynames() {
    return Displayname;
}

public String getEmails() {
    return Email;
}

public Long getCreatedAts() {
    return createdAt;
}
```

My question is how can I get my output to print just: Testing: Chrisharvz

The reason I want to do this is so I can display the user's username as they log into my application, replacing Log.d with Textview.settext etc...

Anyone have an idea?
If you need anymore information, lemme know! :D
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `Users` node is a direct child of your Firebase database root and `0x2s4Ft...` is the `uid` of the logged in user, to get the value only from your `Displayname` field, please use the following code:

```
FirebaseUser firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
String uid = firebaseUser.getUid();

DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child("Users").child(uid);
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String Displayname = dataSnapshot.child("Displayname").getValue(String.class);
        Log.d("Testing: ", Displayname);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Your output will be:

```
Testing: Chrisharvz
```

Comment: That's it! Solved my problem entirely! Thanks a very much, saved me a lot of time!

Answer (score 0):

What I suggest is convert the data back into user object after you retrieve the data from firebase because right now you are using the whole object. You should try this:

```
    fDatabase =FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

    fDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // convert the data back to the model
            User user = (User) dataSnapshot.child(currentUser.getUid()).getValue(User.class);
            // just get the string value for the username
            String displayName = user.getDisplayName() // getter method from your model
            Log.d ("Testing", displayName);
            }
```

Hopefully this helps your problem.

Comment: Thanks bud! Gave it a go but I seem to be getting 'cannot resolve method' on 'currentUser' and 'getDisplayName'.

Comment: currentUser is an object of firebase user so you have to create that. So you have to get the current user object: 

**FirebaseUser currentUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();**

and for the getDisplayName, it is the method from your model class, so you have to import your model class to that activity.

Comment: note: this solution allows you to get all the data from the user object from the database because you are retrieving the whole user object instead of the displayName only. You can get the value of the other attributes by calling the getter method.